# Fancybox won't load inline content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

To make things easy, here's the site - http://schnell.dreamhosters.com/folio/pixelread.php  View the source code all you like.

The middle button of the top bar in your browser window that says "Palette" is supposed to open up a fancybox in the middle of the screen, and that box should load into it the data inside the element with id of 'data', but it doesn't and comes up with an error message of "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later."  I took this example straight from the fancybox website and double-checked that all the CSS, image and JS files are in their proper place and loaded.  So now I'm lost and no idea how to do/fix this.

PS - I use Google Chrome 6.0.  I'll see if this happens in IE8 or Firefox.

PPS - Found a solution.  I can force the HTML content that goes into a fancybox by using the 'content' property.  Using that and jQuery I can easily stuff a box with whatever I want.  Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: When clicking Palette I get a fancybox with the text "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit." in it. If I then click `Megaman` and try Palette again I get the error. I only get the issue when I click `Megaman`, is this the same for you?

Comment: Browser + version might be in order, I cannot reproduce the problem here.

Comment: Ah, the route jakenoble mentions does indeed produce the error here.

Comment: The issue for me is that the button that brings up the window never gets the content it should in it at all.  I always get 'The requested content cannot be loaded.  Please try again later."

Comment: Well this is rather strange but it appears as if fancybox just decided to work fine...

Comment: @jakenoble I'm now getting the same error as you.  Loads fine the first time, but then I switch to someone else and try it and I get the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution. I can force the HTML content that goes into a fancybox by using the 'content' property. Using that and jQuery I can easily stuff a box with whatever I want. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that fancybox isn't recognizing your content as being inline (not exactly sure why, but maybe something to do with the query string in the url, since it works when that isn't present).

I would try adding the explicit `type: inline` to your fancybox declaration:

```
$("a#inline").fancybox({'type':'inline'});
```

Comment: Tried this, but what winds up happening is that it will put the 'palette' link inside the fancybox instead of the div of stuff I want.

Comment: This doesn't work. `$('a.fancybox').fancybox({
  type:'inline',
  closeBtn: false
 });` this is my code, and the thumbnails from the link are what get put into the content instead, so basically fancybox is not reading in the inline content. The documentation for this library is very confusing.